# Is there a way to switch the dimensions order in a multi-dimensional vector?

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I have a 3D vector and I want to be able to chose which dimension to plot as a function of another dimension.

So far, I am doing this manually: I create a second 3D vector and re-organize the data accordingly. This solution is not very practical since I need to switch the indexes (inside the nested loop) every time I want to switch the dimensions...

Is there a better/cleaner solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: You might write a wrapper...

Comment: Look for a mathematical solution. Think of your 3D vector as a function of 3 indices: `v(i,j,k)`. Say you want to plot `k` as a function of `j`. What do you do with `i`? It sounds like your question is incomplete. Giving an example in this context might help.

Comment: Instead of moving data in the 3d vector, how about changing the order of the indices?  Instead of `v[x, y, z]`, try `v[x, z, y]`.   Changing the order of the indicies is easier than moving data around.

Comment: Let's say I have a measure m that depends on 3 variables a,b and c. I want to see how m evolves as a function of a, b and c. I can be interested to display m as a function of "a" (x axis), for a limited number of values of b (number of plots/curves), and a limited number of values of c (number of figures). It depends on which parameter I want to use for the: x-axis, plot/curve index, and figure index.

Comment: Make the axes be parameters of the plotting function. How you do this depends on how your vectors, and the collection of them, are organized. You might even want to redesign to make it easier to select axes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I actually use a similar reasoning. My question is how would I do it without manually replacing the indexes everywhere... How to make this change "centralized".

Comment: I think that to achieve what I want it might be better to use a 1 dimension vector v. For instance I can use a combination of these dimensions to write "m" into the vector and another combination to extract the appropriate data for axis, plot and figure indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not provide multidimensional containers for the same reason that containers like `std::vector` do not provide a standard `operator+` *etc*.: there is no standard that fits everyone's needs (in the case of a `+` operator, this could be concatenation, element-wise addition, increasing the dimensionality, who knows). If instead of a vector you take a class

```
<template typename T>
class volume {

private:
std::vector<T>       data;    // e.g. 3x2 array { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
std::vector<size_t>  sizes;   // e.g. 3x2 array { 3, 2 }
std::vector<size_t>  strides; // e.g. 3x2 array { 1, 3 }

};
```

then you have all the flexibility you want - no need to stop at 3D!

As an example the `data` vector of a 3x2 array could be the first 6 natural numbers, the `sizes` vector would be `{ 3, 2 }` and the strides array `{ 1, 3 }`: in a row (of which there are 2) the elements are next to each other, to increase the row you need to move 3 positions forward.

In the general *n*-dimensional case you can make an `at()` operator that takes a vector (or an `initializer_list`) as a position argument, and the offset corresponding to that position is its inner product with `strides`.

If you don't feel like programming this from scratch then libraries like [Blitz++](https://github.com/blitzpp/blitz) already provide this functionality.

Comment: Like this?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray

Comment: JDługosz, I will look into it if I do not manage to apply solutions such as the ones proposed by alle_meije and Serge. thank you all.

Comment: Must admit I never worked with either valarrays or blitz -- I did it the hard way ...

Answer (score 1):

No.

*<RANT>* C++ has no notion of multidimensional vectors. And has poor support for multidimensional arrays, because arrays are far from first class objects. So you are left with vectors of vectors [of vectors ...] and have to carefully control that all vectors in a containing vector have the same size (the language will **not** help you there). Or with multidimentional raw arrays... provided that the size for all dimensions but the last are known at compile time. *</RANT>*

As the number of dimensions are known (3D) I would go with a dedicated container using a 1D vector of size l*m*n (where l, m, and n are the size in the 3 dimensions). And a dedicated accessor function `data(i,j,k)`. For there, it is possible to build another accessor tool that gives the data in one dimension starting from another one...

If you do not really like all that boiler plate code, you could have a look at the boost libraries. I do not use it, but if I correctly remember it contains a matrix class...

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is consistent with my last comment.